# ellipsis for multiline text in Chrome

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

Is there anything like `-o-ellipsis-lastline` for Google Chrome?

I'm building a Chrome extension and would like to ellipsize multiline text using CSS.

Comment: Do you have any sort of requirement for what browsers you need this to be compatible with? Are you willing to implement a solution that uses Javascript?

Comment: I'm building a Chrome extension, so it only needs to be compatible with Chrome. I would rather not use Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to create ellipsis pure CSS due to [W3 spec for text-overflow](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-text-20021024/#text-overflow-ellipsis).

But If you are developing Chrome Extensions you have already using JavaScript, so here is some demos and plugins to solve your problem:

- http://www.codeitbetter.co.uk/widgets/ellipsis/
- http://jsfiddle.net/danesparza/TF6Rb/1/
- http://jsfiddle.net/MPkSF/
- http://jsfiddle.net/VpmbL/
- https://github.com/pvdspek/jquery.autoellipsis

I'm using the last plugin on my own projects.

Answer (score 0):

At present there is no ellipsis for multiline text... But you can do ellipsis effect for multiline using simple conditions. Here is an example...

Say you have an html like this...

```
<div class="class_name"><%=message%></div>
```

And you render your text at run time... Your text will be rendered and placed in the div tag instead of the message template. So what you can do is...

```
<% if(message.length < 100) { %>
  <div class="class_name"><%=message%></div>
<% } else { %>
  <div class="class_name"><%=message.slice(0,80)%>...</div>
<% } %>
```

If your text is more than 100 characters it will show a ellipsis effect(at the end of 80 characters)

Note: the values 100 and 80 are optional. You can change as you concern...

Hope it helps :)...